# Memory pool algorithms

Tags: c++, opengl, memory-management, vbo, memory-pool

I am looking for smarter algorithms in handling VBOs in OpenGL.

As it stands, I currently store each of my models in 4MB VBO's.
If the model is larger than 4MB, it is stored separately.
The objects are stored such that the models are pooled together to decrease the number of binds.

The problem I am experiencing has been how to clean up unused VBO's, which are using only sparsely being used.
Any resources on how I could better manage these memory pools is appreciated.

Comment: I assume you've already tried just creating and destroying VBOs of the sizes needed and letting the driver handle memory management?  (NB: 4MB != 4096000 bytes)

Comment: @daniel: I'm not suggesting that VBOs only survive a single frame, I'm suggesting that each model has its own VBO, instead of packing them together.  Then you won't have these "most unused" VBOs.  What kind of application is this anyway, that models get unloaded frequently?

Comment: It is just a possible flaw in the system I am using above, the reason I avert individual VBOs is for less binds, esp for static data. As for why 4mb, that is the ATI/Nvidia recommended VBO size. The application isn't necessarily going to be doing frequent unloading, but it was just something I noticed could be an issue.

Comment: @Daniel: If ATI and nVidia are recommending 4MB VBOs, that's the recommended *batch* size as well.  I don't think they are recommending binding 4MB of data and then rendering that 4MB piecemeal.  If you have several different models that have to be rendered interleaved, then loading them into a single VBO is probably a reasonable idea, but that suggests they're closely related and won't be unloaded independently.  Packing unrelated textures into a VBO is like to make performance worse, not better.  And binding a VBO doesn't cost memory throughput, reading or writing from CPU to VBO does.

Comment: @Ben Voigt Put all your comments into an answer perhaps, definetly helpful information :)

Comment: @Daniel I think you misunderstood the purpose of VBOs. They are not there to minimize OpenGL posts. I haven't seen any application doing such a memory pool management of fixed sized VBOs, as they were made to let the driver do that for you and Ben's suggestion is the common way. Actually your post (the one starting with Lol) made me nearly lol.

Comment: Well it sounds like I may have misunderstood VBOs then :/

Comment: @Daniel: The purpose of VBOs is putting the geometry data in a place where it's available fast. Most commonly the GPU's RAM. Or in other words: Using VBOs saves CPU->GPU bandwidth. The part about saving OpenGL calls are Vertex Arrays (instead of immediate mode) and while it is true, that VBOs share/use the vertex array interface the idea behind VBOs (or any kind of buffer object) is to use fast, local memory and save bandwidth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBOs are not like regular memory, there is no need for any kind of sophisticated "memory management". You allocate a own, apropriately sized VBO for each distinct mesh and be done with. Any attempt to outsmart the driver will just result in inferior performance.

Also there is no benefit in attempting to make your VBOs as large as possible. In fact modest sized VBOs of about 0.5k to 5k vertices in my experience work best.

Comment: What do you mean by modes sized?

Comment: Betting it's a typo for "models sized" ! :)

Comment: actually I meant to write "modest" (note the 't')

Answer (score 1):

I originally had something like you do.  I implemented a simple freelist in about 100 lines of code so that freed VBO segments could be reused.  It significantly reduced VBO reallocations which were giving me frame hitches.  I used a best-fit algorithm for allocations because I have many meshes which happen to have the same number of vertexes and faces.

Comment: Could you expand on your solution?